# what the content of the parameter "obc" for /dlfolder/get-folders restful api in liferay?

Tags: liferay

The parameter `obc` for restful api `/dlfolder/get-folders` in liferay requires the type `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.OrderByComparator`.

I tried many possible values but always got the error message

> Unable to cast value to type: com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.OrderByComparator

Now I got stuck in this problem.
Is anyone who know what the value should be put in this parameter, please teach me, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are object as parameters have to put `+` before the parameter and `:` as saparator of full name class like this

```
http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/dlfolder/get-folders/group-id/0/parent-folder-id/0/start/0/end/10/+obc:com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.comparator.FolderNameComparator
```

or javascript

```
Liferay.Service(
  '/dlfolder/get-folders',
  {
    groupId: 0,
    parentFolderId: 0,
    start: 0,
    end: 10,
    "+obc":"com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.comparator.FolderNameComparator"
  },
  function(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
  }
);
```

link to documentation for more info https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/invoking-json-web-services#object-parameters

Comment: I tried it and it worked. It is really help me a lot. Thank you very much.