# liferay 7 jsonws API dlfileentry obc parameter example

Tags: web-services, liferay

I wanto to try the web service of dflservice entry into the web service portal

```
http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws
```

but the parameter used obc just explain as obc with the type com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.OrderByComparator, I try  null, 0, +obc:com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.comparator.FolderNameComparator, but always have the same result:

```
Conversion failed: com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.OrderByComparator
```

What is the correct parameter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907097/what-the-content-of-the-parameter-obc-for-dlfolder-get-folders-restful-api-in?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation:

1. You can't pass `0`, as `obc` is an object type parameter.
2. To pass a `null` value for `obc`, you need to prefix it with a dash like: `/-obc`.
3. And to pass an instance of an object parameter, you need to prefix the parameter with a plus sign like: `/+obc:com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.comparator.FolderNameComparator` (Should work as well).

As `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.OrderByComparator` is an abstract class, you need to pass a concrete implementation. Check the implementation of `DLImpl.getRepositoryModelOrderByComparator` method for further concrete implementations of `OrderByComparator` class for document library.

Also, I would like you to share the URI(s), you are trying. So, I can also try them.

**Reference:**
[**INVOKING JSON WEB SERVICES**](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/invoking-json-web-services)

**Update:**

There is bug in JSONWS GUI, which is already fixed in:
https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-76955?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

However, the URL access is working for me:

http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/dlfileentry/get-file-entries/group-id/10184/folder-id/0/status/0/start/-1/end/-1/+obc:com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.comparator.RepositoryModelNameComparator

Here, `com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.comparator.RepositoryModelNameComparator` is a concrete implementation of `obc`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for yout reply , I use this URI: http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws?contextName=&signature=%2Fdlfileentry%2Fget-file-entries-6-groupId-folderId-status-start-end-obc#serviceResults

Comment: It didn't  work, on the android SDK, either, I try using this :                                   ```try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                    obj.put("obc","com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.comparator.LayoutSetPrototypeCreateDateComparator");
                    JSONObjectWrapper obc = new JSONObjectWrapper(obj);
                    System.out.println(obc.getJSONObject());
                    service2.getFileEntries(20143,38223,0,100,obc);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  ```

Comment: Why would `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.comparator.LayoutSetPrototypeCreateDateComparator` work, this isn't associated with DL api. As, I already told you that see the implementation of `DLImpl.getRepositoryModelOrderByComparator` for further concrete classes.

Comment: As you say, I saw the DLImpl.getrepositoryModelOrderByComparator:  ```getRepositoryModelOrderByComparator(
  String orderByCol, String orderByType, boolean orderByModel) ``` but i want to know how  I could pass a -obc parameter in a android SDK call, I used the  ```+obc:com.liferay.document.library.kernel.util.comparator.RepositoryModelTitleComparator ```  as a parameter and return  a empty array,  in a postman que

Comment: Do you even have records in your DL? Can you share your code?

Comment: Yes I have records, thanks a lot for your help, I using the methods and finally find the error, in the implementation  in the obc parameter using this documentation : [link](https://dev.liferay.com/pt/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/invoking-liferay-services-in-your-android-app)